# Where can I view the log that is sent to the BlueJean support when reporting an issue?

Tags: windows, logging, bluejeans

Where can I view the log that is sent to the BlueJean support when reporting an issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I use BlueJeans 2.19.791.0 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Most applications use one directories within AppData (Local, LocalLow, and Roaming) for log files.  Have you looked within the applicable directory for the application in those directories?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, indeed I just found it on `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\BlueJeans\current\.2020-05-12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I view the log that is sent to the BlueJean support when reporting an issue?

Most applications use one of the directories within AppData (Local, LocalLow, and Roaming) for log files.  In this specific case you can find the log within a directory within `%LocalAppData%\BlueJeans\current\`